# Displaying output without lowercase letters

Tags: linux, string, unix, awk, grep

I have a file with a format :

```
en Zyung 1 630
en zz%20top%20la%20grange%201st%20guitar%20solo 1 657
en Zz%20top%20la%20grange%20remastered 1 652
en.b %7Eobsidian 1 6937
en.b %C3%9Eie_Nummern/3 2 7521
```

I want that the second string after first space that means "zyung" should not have small letter as first letter. I have got:

```
grep -i [a-z] filename
```

But this will act on first character of the line which is wrong. Any suggestion?

Comment: You should make your specification clearer. Does every line begin with `en`? Do you want to filter lines or to transform lines?

Comment: No, lines can begin with en.d or any such string but there is one space between first string "en/en.v/en.d" and the name of the page "Zyung". So space can be best delimiter. I think "should not have small letters" means I want to filter lowercase letter as the first letter of the string.

Comment: you want to extract lines from that file or modify that file?? what is your expected output?

Comment: I want output in a file.

Comment: @CtrlV what is your expected output based on that example???

Comment: @Kent: I agree. Sometimes an output example is worth a thousand of words. It seems that he wants to do the work harder for those who want to help. After 35 minutes I still don't know what he wants to achieve. And the problem apparently doesn't seem too difficult to solve.

Comment: @Birei I guess he was thinking in this way: "what is your expected output?" "I want output to be a file." "ok, what is your expected output?" "oh, you are strange, don't you understand, I said I want output to be a file! a FILE!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this grep:

```
grep -E '^\S*\s+[A-Z]' file
```

test with your example:

```
kent$ echo "en Zyung 1 630
en zz%20top%20la%20grange%201st%20guitar%20solo 1 657
en Zz%20top%20la%20grange%20remastered 1 652"|grep -E '^\S*\s+[A-Z]'
en Zyung 1 630
en Zz%20top%20la%20grange%20remastered 1 652
```

you can see, the 2nd line was filtered out.

**EDIT**

try this line:

```
grep -E '^\S*\s+[^a-z]' file
```

Comment: Thanks this works partially. But the line could start with a special character too so displaying only [A-Z] wont work. See my edited questions. Instead ignoring small letters work.

Comment: try this `grep -E '^\S*\s+[^a-z]'`

Comment: @CtrlV please make a better example, and paste expected output too.

Answer (score 3):

To output lines where the second word does not begin with a lowercase letter (actually, that begins with a character that is not a lowercase letter), use

```
    env LANG=C LC_ALL=C awk '$2 ~ /^[^a-z]/' filename
```

or, to redirect that output to another file

```
    env LANG=C LC_ALL=C awk '$2 ~ /^[^a-z]/' originalfile > newfile
```

To turn the first letter of the second word on each line to uppercase, use

```
    env LANG=C LC_ALL=C awk '{ $2 = toupper(substr($2,1,1)) substr($2,2) } 1' filename
```

or, to redirect to another file,

```
    env LANG=C LC_ALL=C awk '{ $2 = toupper(substr($2,1,1)) substr($2,2) } 1' originalfile > newfile
```

Do not use `originalfile` == `newfile`, as that will not work. The shell will clear the file first (as it is redirected output, `> newfile`) before the command is even started. You will just end up with an empty file.

The `env LANG=C LC_ALL=C` additions avoid the case where you are using GNU awk and a non-POSIX locale; there `gawk` matches `[a-z]` to any letter, not just lowercase letters. If you want locale-aware behaviour, use either non-gawk awk, say `mawk`, or like Jotne suggested, `^[^[:lower:]]` instead of `^[^a-z]`.

Comment: for some reason this didn't filter what I needed. Your second solution is closest to what I am looking for. Thanks anyways @Nominal Animal

Comment: @CtrlV: Good thing you noticed. I missed the `^` at the start of the pattern (so that it only matches at the start of the string). Fixed now.

Comment: You should change `/^[^a-z]/` to `/^[^[:lower:]]/`. Its much more robust. My ubuntu gets same result for `a-z` and `A-Z`, both gives both upper and lower case.

Comment: @Jotne: Hardly more robust, as that behaviour is specific to GNU awk (`gawk`). (`mawk` et al. do not support character classes like `[:lower:]`, you see.) But thanks for the heads up; I added a different fix, and added some text that might help if others run into similar issues.